# PyInstaller and Poppler

Tags: pyqt, pyinstaller, poppler

Im working on an Python application that can show pdf files. I tried to use 
the [python-poppler-qt4](http://code.google.com/p/python-poppler-qt4/) Binding.

So far no problem. 
But it is also neceseery that  i can build a stand alone executable of the programm.
For this I want to use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org).

It seems that PyInstaller doesnt support Poppler. How can I go around this?

Comment: Any update? I'm also having trouble including poppler to my standalone exe made from pyinstaller

Answer (score 2):

What is the issue that you are hitting?

I've written quite a few programs for Windows packaged using PyInstaller using python-poppler-qt4 and the only problem I had was that the `PyQt4.QtXml` dependency wasn't imported automatically.

This can be fixed by creating a file named `hook-popplerqt4.py` with the contents:

```
hiddenimports = ['PyQt4.QtXml']
```

Save this file with the other hooks in

```
<PyInstaller Root>/PyInstaller/hooks
```

and you should be good to go.

If you're still getting issues, post your error so that we have a better idea of what the problem is.